# "ppc64el" of "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)"

Tags: 16.04

Is "ppc64el" of "Ubuntu 16.04 (http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)" the correct choice for a Windows 7 laptop, running on  64-bit Celeron dual core CPU T3500? If not, what should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

No, you want `amd64`, which is for 64-bit x86 CPUs from AMD or Intel, which is what you have.

[`ppc64el`](https://wiki.debian.org/ppc64el) is for IBM POWER8 CPUs, which you don't have.